# Is SharedPreference a good way to store large chunks of data?

Tags: android, performance, sharedpreferences

I'm currently storing large chunks of user data as JSON string in SharedPreferences. It's working nicely but I wonder if it will cause any problems, for example large app size or memory problems.

Are there any better or recommended way to store large chunks of data in Android app, other than SharedPreferences?

Comment: `SharedPreferences` is mostly used to store key value type of data

Comment: @NJ Then what's used to store big datas?

Comment: sqlite or file..

Comment: You can always use `SQlite` database or File

Comment: if you feel comfortable to store JSON inside XML you can use SharedPreferences ... plain json file could be better

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Why? What about sql, read &write files..?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just store it in SQLite DB? You can organise the data in a well format.

Comment: Is it similar to MySQL? Can you refer me to any good tutorial for SQLite use with Android?

Comment: One simple google search on `sqlite android tutorial` and you got plenty...

Comment: This sqlite tutorial helps me a lot to understand sqlite. Hope it helps - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BUljVIgnoE

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not good practice to save large data in `SharedPreference`. You can store large data in either database or create a read or writable file.

You can create readable & writable file like

Write file by this method

```
public static void writeToFile(String data,Context context, String fileName) {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(fileName+".txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Read file by this method

```
    public static String readFromFile(Context context, String fileName) {

        String ret = "";

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput(fileName + ".txt");

            if ( inputStream != null ) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader       = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String receiveString                = "";
                StringBuilder stringBuilder         = new StringBuilder();

                while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                    stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
                }

                inputStream.close();
                ret = stringBuilder.toString();
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "File not found: " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("login activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Can this file be accessed by other apps?

Comment: File writable files?? if you are talking about writable files then No, you can't access from other files.

Comment: Will this file be saved inside the app or the phone storage?